# Rhc setup command error

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, cloud, openshift

my rhc setup command not working for openshift installation, i have recheck all the ruby, rubygems and git version, all of them show me the newest version 

chikin@chikin-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full
[sudo] password for chikin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ruby-full is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.

chikin@chikin-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install rubygems 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
rubygems is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.

chikin@chikin-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install git-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
git-core is already the newest version.

## the problem come when i try the rhc setup commnad,it show me something i really dont know about it 
 chikin@chikin-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem install rhc

If this is your first time installing the RHC tools, please run 'rhc setup'

===========================================================================
Successfully installed rhc-1.35.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rhc-1.35.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rhc-1.35.1...

chikin@chikin-VirtualBox:~$ rhc setup 
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:236: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
        .compact
         ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:462: odd number list for Hash
          title: @title,
                ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:462: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
          title: @title,
                ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:463: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          percent_complete: percent_complete,
                           ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:464: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          progress_bar: progress_bar,
                       ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:465: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          step: @step,
               ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:466: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          steps_remaining: steps_remaining,
                          ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:467: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          total_steps: @total_steps,
                      ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:468: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          time_elapsed: '%0.2fs' % time_elapsed,
                       ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:468: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:470: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
        }.merge! @tokens
         ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander.rb:27
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc.rb:30
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/cli.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.35.1/bin/rhc:18
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a newer version of ruby.  Try at least 1.9.3, which supports the new symbol syntax.

```
symbol: "value"
```

instead of

```
:symbol => "value"
```

Comment: how to get the newest ruby version ? because i am very new to openshift

Comment: try using rvm or rbenv, or a newer version of your operating system

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rhc (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.7.9, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, minitest-5.4.3, power_assert-0.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.0.8] (Gem::LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
 from /usr/local/bin/rhc:18

Comment: i have follow your comment to update the newest rvm but it give up this message when i key in rhc setup, can i know what is the problem ?

Comment: If it's still showing that you are using ruby 1.8, then you aren't using rvm correctly.

Comment: I still get back the old error message but the rvm version is the new one.i follow the youtuube link for the upgrading tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-xSFdB5EQQ this is the video I refer for upgrading the ruby

Comment: You need to install a newer version of ruby using rvm, and then 'rvm use' it, you are still using the old version of 1.8

Comment: I do all the thing already, all the command I refer to that youtube link I provided in the previous comment ,but the problem still the same